# How to customise file input styles?

Tags: html, css

I have to make a file input field where a user has to click to open the files explorer and select his résumé. It should look like this:

[image]

Here is so far what I got:

```html
<input type="file" name="mobile_num" placeholder="Attach Resume" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

File `input` is one of those `html` elements that it is hard to control the `style`, every browser has its particular way with it. But there are some techniques to use, and here is one of them :

```css
.group {
  position: relative;
}

.group .btn {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  border-raduis: 5px;
}
.group input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <button class="btn">Attach Resume</button>
  <input type="file" name="mobile_num" placeholder="Attach Resume" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks It helps me a lot and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add label element and use for attribute will resolve your issue. I also update code snippet, I hope it'll help you out. Thank you

```css
.group {
  position: relative;
}

.group .btn {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  border-raduis: 5px;
}
.group input {
  display: none;
}
.group label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <button class="btn">Attach Resume</button>
  <label for="mobile_num"></label>
  <input id="mobile_num" type="file" name="mobile_num" placeholder="Attach Resume" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- **Step 1**: Add a label tag as the parent of your file input
- **Step 2**: Add    some CSS to hide the default file input and display the
  label as per    your reference image

```css
.file_input_btn {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: grey;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.file_input_btn input {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<label for="file_input" class="file_input_btn">
  Attach Resume
<input type="file" id="file_input" name="mobile_num" required>
</label>
```